# How do I replace all duplicate values in Excel with a formula?

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, formula

I'm trying to replace all duplicate values in my spreadsheet with an original value via a formula. However, I'm finding it really hard to use the correct formula to perform this action.

I have multiple apple entries in my spreadsheet with a corresponding number beside them.

On 22/10/2016, I received 2 apples. On the 23rd, I received 4, and so on.

```
Number | Item
2      | Apple
4      | Apple
5      | Apple
```

My pseudo-code looks something like this:

IF duplicate item is found, replace all number values with an original value (2).

Can someone help me out with a formula, I don't use excel too much.

Any information would help, and/or if you were to point me into the right direction, that would be most beneficial.

If you would like any more information about my problem, then please ask away and I'll try construct this problem better for you.

Thank you for your help.

EDIT: Keep in mind, I may also have other duplicate values in my sheet. I only want the formula to effect apples in this case, and bananas in a different formula.

Comment: Since you want to _replace_ values in different cells then you need VBA for this. UDF can't change cells other than the ones they are called in (if not by means of some dangerous tricks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use vba, you can use a formula (INDEX MATCH) as well to get your desired result.

As you can see in the picture below, this formula looks for the first occurrance of the word in column B and returns it's corresponding value in column A.
[image]